# ACF Repeater field pagination on homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Field plugin on my website to show products. I need to implement pagination to Repeater Field loop after showing 8 products. I found solution here -> http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2014/03/06/paginating-an-advanced-custom-fields-repeater/ and this works great but not on the homepage. I was tested on mydomain.com/test and second page showing at mydomain.com/test/2 but on homepage site mydomain.com/2 showing 404 error.

My code at template-home.php

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <?php
    $promocja = pll__('PROMOCJA!');
    $zobacz = pll__('Zobacz produkt'); ?>


    <div class="container productLoopContainer">
        <div class="row">

        <?php
        if( get_query_var('page') ) {
            $page = get_query_var( 'page' );
        } else {
            $page = 1;
        }

        $row              = 0;
        $cols_per_page    = 8; // How many images to display on each page
        $cols             = get_field( 'produkt' );
        $total            = count( $cols );
        $pages            = ceil( $total / $cols_per_page );
        $min              = ( ( $page * $cols_per_page ) - $cols_per_page ) + 1;
        $max              = ( $min + $cols_per_page ) - 1;

        if( have_rows('produkt') ) :

            while ( have_rows('produkt') ) : the_row();

                $row++;

                // Ignore this image if $row is lower than $min
                if($row < $min) { continue; }

                // Stop loop completely if $row is higher than $max
                if($row > $max) { break; }    

                $kategoria = get_sub_field('kategoria');
                $urlProduktu = get_sub_field('adres_url');
                $zdjecie = get_sub_field('zdjecie');
                $nazwa = get_sub_field('nazwa_produktu'); ?>

                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="product clearfix product-hover" id="<?php echo $kategoria; ?>">
                            <div class="left">
                                <div class="sale-badge"><?php echo $promocja; ?></div>
                                <div class="image">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $urlProduktu; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $zdjecie; ?>" class="zoom-image-effect wp-post-image" alt="<?php echo $nazwa; ?>"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <div class="name"><a href="<?php echo $urlProduktu; ?>"><?php echo $nazwa; ?></a></div>
                                <div class="typo-actions clearfix">
                                    <div class="addtocart">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $urlProduktu; ?>" class="button cart-links add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart product_type_variable"><?php echo $zobacz; ?></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            <?php endwhile;

            // Pagination
              echo paginate_links( array(
                'base' => get_permalink() . '%#%' . '/',
                'format' => '?page=%#%',
                'current' => $page,
                'total' => $pages
              ) ); ?>

        <?php else: 
            // no rows found
        endif; ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Have you an idea how to fix this issue? I was trying with adding rewrite_endpoint in functions.php but without success.

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE:
I added code to functions.php and a little bit change my template code and now there is no 404. Second page showing at mydomain.com/products/2 which is great but there is no products - instead of showing products there is only word "ARCHIVES".

My template:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <?php
    $promocja = pll__('PROMOCJA!');
    $zobacz = pll__('Zobacz produkt'); ?>


    <div class="container productLoopContainer">
        <div class="row">

        <?php
        // Get query var
                    global $wp_rewrite;
                    if ($wp_rewrite->using_permalinks()) {
                            if( !empty( get_query_var('products'))) {
                                    $page = get_query_var('products');
                            } else {
                                    $page = 1;
                            }
                    } else {
                            if( !empty( $_GET['products'] )) {
                                    $page = $_GET['products'];
                            } else {
                                    $page = 1;
                            }
                    }

        $row              = 0;
        $cols_per_page    = 8; // How many images to display on each page
        $cols             = get_field( 'produkt' );
        $total            = count( $cols );
        $pages            = ceil( $total / $cols_per_page );
        $min              = ( ( $page * $cols_per_page ) - $cols_per_page ) + 1;
        $max              = ( $min + $cols_per_page ) - 1;

        if( have_rows('produkt') ) :

            while ( have_rows('produkt') ) : the_row();

                $row++;

                // Ignore this image if $row is lower than $min
                if($row < $min) { continue; }

                // Stop loop completely if $row is higher than $max
                if($row > $max) { break; }    

                $kategoria = get_sub_field('kategoria');
                $urlProduktu = get_sub_field('adres_url');
                $zdjecie = get_sub_field('zdjecie');
                $nazwa = get_sub_field('nazwa_produktu'); ?>

                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="product clearfix product-hover" id="<?php echo $kategoria; ?>">
                            <div class="left">
                                <div class="sale-badge"><?php echo $promocja; ?></div>
                                <div class="image">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $urlProduktu; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $zdjecie; ?>" class="zoom-image-effect wp-post-image" alt="<?php echo $nazwa; ?>"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <div class="name"><a href="<?php echo $urlProduktu; ?>"><?php echo $nazwa; ?></a></div>
                                <div class="typo-actions clearfix">
                                    <div class="addtocart">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $urlProduktu; ?>" class="button cart-links add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart product_type_variable"><?php echo $zobacz; ?></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            <?php endwhile;

            // Pagination
               if ($pages > 1) {
                            repeater_pagination($page, $pages, 3);
                    } 
                    ?>

        <?php else: 
            // no rows found
        endif; ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and functions.php:

```
function repeater_pagination($paged = 1, $pages = '', $range = 2) {
$showitems = ($range * 2) + 1;
if(1 != $pages) {
    echo "<ul class='pager'>";
    // Arrows left
    if ($paged > 1) echo "<li class='previous'><a href='".get_repeater_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'><i class='icon-arrow-left'></i></a></li>";
    // Numbers
    for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
            if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems )) {
                    echo ($paged == $i)? "<li class='active'><a href='".get_repeater_pagenum_link($i)."'>".$i."</a></li>":"<li><a href='".get_repeater_pagenum_link($i)."'>".$i."</a></li>";
            }
    }
    // Arrows right
    if ($paged < $pages) echo "<li class='next'><a href='".get_repeater_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'><i class='icon-arrow-right'></i></a></li>";
    echo "</ul>\n";
  }
}

function get_repeater_pagenum_link($pagenum = 1) {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $pagenum = (int) $pagenum;
    $pageslug = 'products';
    $request = remove_query_arg('products');

$home_root = parse_url(home_url());
$home_root = ( isset($home_root['path']) ) ? $home_root['path'] : '';
$home_root = preg_quote( trailingslashit( $home_root ), '|' );
$request = preg_replace('|^'. $home_root . '|', '', $request);
$request = preg_replace('|^/+|', '', $request);

// Normal Permalinks
if ( !$wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() || is_admin() ) {
    $base = trailingslashit( get_bloginfo( 'url' ) );
    if ( $pagenum > 1 ) {
            $result = add_query_arg('products', $pagenum, $base . `$request);`
    } else {
            $result = $base . $request;
    }
// Pretty Permalinks   
} else {
    $qs_regex = '|\?.*?$|';
    preg_match( $qs_regex, $request, $qs_match );
    if ( !empty( $qs_match[0] ) ) {
            $query_string = $qs_match[0];
            $request = preg_replace( $qs_regex, '', $request );
    } else {
            $query_string = '';
    }
    $request = preg_replace( "|$pageslug/\d+/?$|", '', $request);
    $request = preg_replace( '|^index\.php|', '', $request);
    $request = ltrim($request, '/');
    $base = trailingslashit( get_bloginfo( 'url' ) );

    if ( $wp_rewrite->using_index_permalinks() && ( $pagenum > 1 || '' != $request ) )
            $base .= 'index.php/';

    if ( $pagenum > 1 ) {
            $request = ( ( !empty( $request ) ) ? trailingslashit( $request ) : $request ) . user_trailingslashit( $pageslug . "/" . $pagenum, 'paged' );
    }

    $result = $base . $request . $query_string;
}
$result = apply_filters('get_repeater_pagenum_link', $result);
return $result;
}

/* Products pagination parameter */
function add_products_query_var(){
    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var('products');
}
/* Use EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES for pages and posts both */
function products_rewrite_endpoint(){
  add_rewrite_endpoint('products', EP_ALL);
}
add_filter('init', 'add_products_query_var');
add_filter('init', 'products_rewrite_endpoint');
```

Comment: You can try using 'paged' instead of 'page' ( get_query_var ) on home or blog pages.

Comment: @YuxelYuseinov unfortunately problem still occurs.

Comment: what is your post type slug name?

Comment: This is my template for my homepage called /* Template Name: SG */

Answer (score 0):

add below code in template

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <?php
        $promocja = pll__('PROMOCJA!');
        $zobacz = pll__('Zobacz produkt'); ?>

        <div class="container productLoopContainer">

                <?php
                /* Template Loop */

                        // Get query var
                        global $wp_rewrite;
                        if ($wp_rewrite->using_permalinks()) {
                                if( !empty( get_query_var('products'))) {
                                        $page = get_query_var('products');
                                } else {
                                        $page = 1;
                                }
                        } else {
                                if( !empty( $_GET['products'] )) {
                                        $page = $_GET['products'];
                                } else {
                                        $page = 1;
                                }
                        }
                        // Variables
                        $i              = 0;
                        $productspp       = 8;
                        $products         = get_field('produkt');
                        $total          = count($products);
                        $pages          = ceil($total / $productspp);
                        $min            = (($page * $productspp) - $productspp) + 1;
                        $max            = ($min + $productspp) - 1;
                        // Loop
                        if( have_rows('produkt')) { ?>
                                <div class="row">
                                        <?php while(have_rows('produkt')): the_row(); $i++;
                                                /* Ignore this row, if $i is lower than $min */
                                                if($i < $min) {continue; }
                                                /* Stop loop completely, if $i is higher than $max */
                                                if($i > $max) {break; }                        
                                                /* Close row after 3 products and start new one */
                                                //if($c == 4): $c = 0; 
                                                // endif; 

                                                $kategoria = get_sub_field('kategoria');
                                                $urlProduktu = get_sub_field('adres_url');
                                                $zdjecie = get_sub_field('zdjecie');
                                                $nazwa = get_sub_field('nazwa_produktu');
                                               ?>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                                            <div class="product clearfix product-hover" id="<?php echo $kategoria; ?>">
                                                                <div class="left">
                                                                    <div class="sale-badge"><?php echo $promocja; ?></div>
                                                                    <div class="image">
                                                                        <a href="<?php echo $urlProduktu; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $zdjecie; ?>" class="zoom-image-effect wp-post-image" alt="<?php echo $nazwa; ?>"></a>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="right">
                                                                    <div class="name"><a href="<?php echo $urlProduktu; ?>"><?php echo $nazwa; ?></a></div>
                                                                    <div class="typo-actions clearfix">
                                                                        <div class="addtocart">
                                                                            <a href="<?php echo $urlProduktu; ?>" class="button cart-links add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart product_type_variable"><?php echo $zobacz; ?></a>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>  
                                                <?php $c++; // column count
                                endwhile; ?>

                        </div> 
                        <?php } else { ?>
                                <p><?php _e('No produkt found','mytextdomain'); ?></p>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <!-- Pagination -->
                        <?php if ($pages > 1) {
                                repeater_pagination($page, $pages, 3);
                        } 
                        ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

add below code in function.php

```
<?php
/* ==========================================================================
   ACF Repeater Field Pagination (in functions.php)
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * Custom bootstrap pagination for custom ACF repeater field array
 */
function repeater_pagination($paged = 1, $pages = '', $range = 2) {
        $showitems = ($range * 2) + 1;
        if(1 != $pages) {
                echo "<ul class='pager'>";
                // Arrows left
                if ($paged > 1) echo "<li class='previous'><a href='".get_repeater_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'><i class='icon-arrow-left'></i></a></li>";
                // Numbers
                for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
                        if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems )) {
                                echo ($paged == $i)? "<li class='active'><a href='".get_repeater_pagenum_link($i)."'>".$i."</a></li>":"<li><a href='".get_repeater_pagenum_link($i)."'>".$i."</a></li>";
                        }
                }
                // Arrows right
                if ($paged < $pages) echo "<li class='next'><a href='".get_repeater_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'><i class='icon-arrow-right'></i></a></li>";
                echo "</ul>\n";
        }
}

/**
 * Custom get_pagenum_link() function for custom paged links
 */
function get_repeater_pagenum_link($pagenum = 1) {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $pagenum = (int) $pagenum;
        $pageslug = 'products';
        $request = remove_query_arg('products');

        $home_root = parse_url(home_url());
        $home_root = ( isset($home_root['path']) ) ? $home_root['path'] : '';
        $home_root = preg_quote( trailingslashit( $home_root ), '|' );
        $request = preg_replace('|^'. $home_root . '|', '', $request);
        $request = preg_replace('|^/+|', '', $request);

        // Normal Permalinks
        if ( !$wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() || is_admin() ) {
                $base = trailingslashit( get_bloginfo( 'url' ) );
                if ( $pagenum > 1 ) {
                        $result = add_query_arg('products', $pagenum, $base . $request);
                } else {
                        $result = $base . $request;
                }
        // Pretty Permalinks   
        } else {
                $qs_regex = '|\?.*?$|';
                preg_match( $qs_regex, $request, $qs_match );
                if ( !empty( $qs_match[0] ) ) {
                        $query_string = $qs_match[0];
                        $request = preg_replace( $qs_regex, '', $request );
                } else {
                        $query_string = '';
                }
                $request = preg_replace( "|$pageslug/\d+/?$|", '', $request);
                $request = preg_replace( '|^index\.php|', '', $request);
                $request = ltrim($request, '/');
                $base = trailingslashit( get_bloginfo( 'url' ) );

                if ( $wp_rewrite->using_index_permalinks() && ( $pagenum > 1 || '' != $request ) )
                        $base .= 'index.php/';

                if ( $pagenum > 1 ) {
                        $request = ( ( !empty( $request ) ) ? trailingslashit( $request ) : $request ) . user_trailingslashit( $pageslug . "/" . $pagenum, 'paged' );
                }

                $result = $base . $request . $query_string;
        }
        $result = apply_filters('get_repeater_pagenum_link', $result);
        return $result;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Rewrite Rules
   ========================================================================== */

/* Products pagination parameter */
function add_products_query_var(){
        global $wp;
        $wp->add_query_var('products');
}
/* Use EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES for pages and posts both */
function products_rewrite_endpoint(){
  add_rewrite_endpoint('products', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES);
}
add_filter('init', 'add_products_query_var');
add_filter('init', 'products_rewrite_endpoint');
?>
```

Comment: Still the same :(

Comment: This code don't work at all. Showing only 4 products and there is no pagination links and footer (something must be wrong).
But I fit this code to my code (see update for my main post) and now it's little bit better because there is no 404 error at mydomain.com/2. Now second page showing at mydomain.com/products/2 but without products - only showing word "ARCHIVES"...